# Java - dynamic changing jLabel text according to data received from serial port

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, serial-port, event-dispatch-thread

i'm working on software for warehouse management (for storing clothes). All items in warehouse have rfid inside, with unique id stored as a String. 
I'm trying to make module that will allow users to read rfid from item by antenna and automatically show received ID in one of GUI's `jLabels`. Antenna is connected with PC by `rs232`. 
I've managed to make class to read data from antenna and it works fine. It opens port to communication, sets properties and reads data when available (through `SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE event`). 
But then I've encountered problem:
I want instance of that class running in different thread so antenna will be waiting for scan and every time after scan jLabel will be changed according to item's ID (later on i will be doing more complex operations on this ID connected with my database but now i just want it to be shown somewhere).
I'm beginning my Java adventure and I don't know how to handle multithreading.
In this case I would like to start scanning from my Netbeans GUI `jFrame` and while the scanning will be in progress the `jFrame` should dynamically refresh value of `jLabel` according to last scanned item. 
Scenario: 
User presses the button to start scanning, scans some ammount of items, ID of each scanned item goes to `jLabel (jReadLabel)` for the time between scans, and when scanning is complete user presses button to stop, so app knows when to stop the thread.
I've made getter method in my ReadCOM class (`getChipID()`) but i don't know how to pass data to jFrame every time when event occured.
Here is what I've done so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.comm.*;

public class ReadCOM implements Runnable, SerialPortEventListener {

static CommPortIdentifier portId;
static CommPortIdentifier saveportId;
static Enumeration portList;
InputStream inputStream;
SerialPort serialPort;
public static Thread readThread;
static OutputStream outputStream;
static boolean outputBufferEmptyFlag = false;
public String defaultPort;
boolean isRunning = true;
private String chip_id="";

public CzytajCOM(CommPortIdentifier portId, String defaultPort) {

    this.defaultPort = defaultPort;
    try {
        serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("Magazyn", 2000);
    } catch (PortInUseException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Error. Port in use.");
    }

    try {
        inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    try {
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);
    } catch (TooManyListenersException e) {
    }
    serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
    try {
        serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600, SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
    } catch (UnsupportedCommOperationException e) {
    }
    readThread = new Thread(this);
    readThread.start();       
}

public void initwritetoport() {

    try {
        outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    try {
        serialPort.notifyOnOutputEmpty(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.exit(-1);
    }

}

public void writetoport() {
}

public void run() {

    while (isRunning) {
        try {
            while (isRunning) {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }
}

public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch (event.getEventType()) {
        case SerialPortEvent.BI:
        case SerialPortEvent.OE:
        case SerialPortEvent.FE:
        case SerialPortEvent.CD:
        case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
        case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
        case SerialPortEvent.RI:
            break;

        case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
            break;

        case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:

            Object obj = event.getSource();
            if (obj instanceof javax.comm.SerialPort) {
                serialPort = (SerialPort) obj;
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));
                    chip_id = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    //System.out.println("Data: "+chip_id);
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println("Reading from device failed!");
                }
            }
            break;
    }
}

public boolean isRunning() {
    return isRunning;
}

public String getChipId() {
    return chip_id;
}

public void setIsRunning(boolean isRunning) {
    this.isRunning = isRunning;
}
```

}
And in my jFrame file here's the code of ButtonActionPerformed (the button which starts and stops reading, the part where im lost...):

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
     if(isRead==false) {
          jStatus.setText("Reading in progress...");
          jLabel1.setText("Press the button to stop reading.");
          isRead=true;
          try {
        portId1=CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier("COM4");
        ReadCOM reader=new ReadCOM(portId1, portId1.getName());
        reader.setIsRunning(true); //
        jReadLabel.setText(reader.getChipId());
              }
    catch (Exception ex){
                    System.out.println("Error in button pressed method.");
                   }
     }
               else {

        jStatus.setText("Reading stopped.");
        jLabel1.setText("Press the button to start reading.");
        isRead=false;
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_jButton1ActionPerformed
```

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling
`Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.
See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.  (a little later, but with 'the link').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) method `setText()` is declared as thread safe but works untill current thread isn't freezed by `Thread.sleep(int)`,

2) method `setText()` works wrapped into `invokeLater()` from `Runnable#run()` or `util.Timer#run()`, but your `Thread.sleep(int)` is outside of those APIs, then potentially can locking events to the `EventDispatchThread`

3) you opening `CommPort` from `ActionListener`, then Swing GUI is freeze or isn't unresponsible untill all events from `ActionListener` ended, nothing could be dispayed in `JLabel`

4) you have to move (reading value from CommPort) to the Background task

- invoke `CommPort` from `Runnable.Thread` or from `util.Timer` (then not required pausing loop by using `Thread.sleep()`)

but most better and I'd suggest to use

- invoke from `SwingWorker`, then you can use `Thread.sleep()` or `util.Timer` inside method `doInBackground()` and output from methods `publish()` or `process()` could be invoke events on `EDT`

Comment: Sorry for delay, I've been injuried after car accident for almost a month :/ Thanks alot for your tips @mKorbel - that was exactly what I needed! I've used SwingWorker approach with publish(chip_id) inside event handler and it works perfectly fine now. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

From your serial port-reading thread execute this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
  // code that updates the label's contents
}});
```

So it's a push-approach: you don't pull the rfid, you push it into the GUI, taking special care that such code is executed on the Event-Dispatching Thread (EDT). That's what `invokeLater` is for.